# What might cause a flash drive to only work when partially pulled out?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

The other night I was transferring some files from my flash drive to my Windows 10 PC, and File Explorer crashed mid transfer.  I removed the flash drive, but when I inserted it again File Explorer popped up an all white window that again froze and crashed.

Since then, none of my laptops recognize the flash drive when it is fully inserted. However, they all briefly detect and mount the drive as I am pulling it out of the port. The sequence basically goes like this:

- I insert the drive fully
- I wait 30 seconds and nothing happens
- The drive is not shown in file explorer or in partition manager
- I slowly pull the drive out and at some midpoint (the drive is partway out) the PC recognizes it
- At this point, File Explorer opens and displays all the files on the drive
- After about half a second, file explorer closes again and when I reopen it the device is not shown

Interestingly, inserting the drive to the same midpoint does not produce the same effect.  My PC only detects the drive when it is fully inserted and then pulled partway back out.  I have tried the drive on another Win 10 laptop and a laptop running Linux Mint, and the results are more or less the same on all laptops in all USB ports.

Even more interestingly, the receiver for my wireless mouse is beginning to display the same behavior - it only works when pushed all the way in, and then slightly pulled back out.  Again, the behavior is the same for all ports in all laptops.

The only half-baked theory I can come up with is that one of the USB ports on my primary laptop is damaging the pins in USB devices I connect to it. But I can't see any obvious physical damage to the pins in either the flash drive or the mouse receiver.

Does anyone here have any ideas what might cause a usb device to not work unless inserted and then partially extracted? If I can start there I'm hoping I can work my way back to the root cause.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a USB3 drive in a USB3 port?

Comment: Slightly broken pin or contact in the connector. Pushing the pin (inserting) breaks the contact. Pulling it (removing it) shifts it back into position and makes contact. Contacts work by friction and generally are sprung so that they apply some tension but it is possible that something is lodged behind the sprung contact (plastic or other debris) that means that there is no give in the spring and friction is too high, causing it to damage connectors that are fitted to it.

Comment: @user1686 It is a USB 3 drive, but it is exhibiting the same behavior in both usb 3 and 2 ports.

Comment: @Mokubai that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: You should very carefully check all your USB connectors for bent pins and absolutely not use any suspect devices except to get important data from them. A damaged pin could potentially damage other connectors it is fitted to and cause a weird sort of transferable "broken connector plague". I've seen it with some spring connector types in the past where the spring contacts cause a weird mutual destruction and then you try it in another device which damages that one in a similar way. https://www.google.com/search?q=usb+connector+bent+pin

Comment: For Mice and USB sticks you should preferably replace them. For ports on your computer you should either use only ports you trust or have a permanently connected hub so that you limit the damage to either connector.

Comment: @Mokubai - your 'plague' comment is a good catch. I once knew of a display card that killed 3 motherboards before anyone realised. 'Let's try it in another PC'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very likely cause of the device working when "wiggled" is a broken solder joint where the USB connector pins meet the the PCB, as shown below.

[image: USB Male Connector]

If you have a very fine-tipped soldering iron, you can try to reflow solder at each pin. *Be careful to avoid electrostatic discharge while handling the device.* Though I would think twice about resoldering an expensive device, there's little loss if it further damages the flash drive.

Comment: Small addition to the answer, using flux this makes solder flow smoother and this type of soldering job 10 times easier. Not really instructional videos but for inspiration perhaps, https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSL85pYTZnmu-CeZkxyXUIlQ7iosvq3hs